How to tweak the mobile version of these custom fields?
This is how the custom fields in my form look like on desktop:

This is on mobile:

The delete button (trash can) is supposed to remove the whole custom field (Key, Type, and Value). But in the mobile version, it looks as if it only deletes the Value.
How to solve this visual issue?

Maybe this is enough? https://i.sstatic.net/mMlCxoDs.png

You need to introduce some kind of grouping.
Either use a panel (Card) or a separator (vertical spacer) or Divider (horizontal line). Maybe add a title/header to each group, even if it is just a numbering, like 1., 2., 3., etc.
You could even use a List to neatly group the input fields with the delete button (and/or allow swiping to delete entries from the list).
The Add and Submit buttons probably should go to a bottom sheet (always visible panel at the bottom).

We can take approach of Google Forms design. There is separation of sections with dividers and inactive sections are in read-only format so that it doesn't take much space.
reference

